# I haven't received an offer letter from a company that I was selected

Tags: job-offer, new-job, india, hiring, fresher

It's been more than 8 months since I was informed that I have been selected to work for this MNC in the oil and gas industry, here in India.

They started the on boarding process of the new recruits in june 2019.I've been in touch with them ever since and the only response I get is that they haven't received any confirmation from their project and that they'd contact me once they receive the same. Its December 2019 now, and I haven't joined the company.It is a sort of a dream job for any fresher engineer and that is why I've been holding on to it. They haven't given any definite date and the only thing that they say is that they will ask me to join for sure, sometime in the near future.I am extremely worried about this and so are my parents.Expert guidance on what to do next would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you already graduate 8 months ago? Or are you yet to graduate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Why are your parents worried? Just continue working in your current job. If you dont have one, get one asap. What you always need to remember: a contract that has not been signed (or at least sent out) is nothing.

Answer (score 5):

> they haven't received any confirmation from their project and that they'd contact me

A MNC has a lot of moving parts, schedules, and agendas for things to take a long time. What they told you basically was, you were selected *for that project* but *we don't know if we need you yet*.

**You do not have an offer**.

Keep interviewing, keep looking for jobs. Put this behind you. If their situation changes they'll contact you, but don't make yourself dependent on them because they do not depend on you either.